# How to configure Cloudfront for API Gateway with API key enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-api-gateway

I configured two `API Gateways` one with `API-key` enabled and the other with `API-key` disabled.

For both the API gateways I configured and enabled `CloudFront`.

For the `API-gateway` which has API-key disabled, the request is served from `CloudFront`.

However, for the API-gateway which has API-key enabled the request is always served from the origin.
In the response from API-gateway with API-key enabled, the 'X-Cache' header always comes with the value `RefreshHit from CloudFront`.

Is this how it will work?

Can I not enable `CDN` for API gateways with `API key`?